# How to read CSV file in C#, which doesn't have value in single column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, excel-2010

I'm trying to read CSV file in C# code as sample here. This CSV file has three columns out of which one column doesn't have value in few rows. So It is consider as new line backslash (\") in C# StreamReader. When I open file in Notepad++ it shows as image below:

[image]

But in MS Excel it shows nothing on that column as per below image

[image]

Here, both Notepad++ and MS Excel shows data differently. In Notepad++ it shows "" where in Excel it shows empty value. Whenever we are reading file through below mention C# code it takes the format as shown in Notepad++.

> Read CSV code

```
    protected List<string> ReadFile(string filePath)
    {
        List<string> content = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader csvReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;

            while ((line = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.Count(x => x == ',') >= 1)
                    {
                        content.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return content;
    }
```

Currently it is cutting down the current row in C# and it moves in second iteration of loop.

please see this screenshots :

1) With full Data

[image]

2) With blank data, row is break down in 2 parts this is part 1

[image]

3) With blank data, row is break down in 2 parts this is part 2

[image]

> Expected O/P : It should consider it as one row in C# code.

How I can handle this scenario in C# code?

Comment: So what will be the output you expected?

Comment: There are correctly-written libraries to read CSV. Use one of those.

Comment: that are not handle this scenario

Comment: @er-mfahhgk please see the updated quetion with o/p

Comment: I don't think it "considers" a blank value as new line, I think that CSV file actually has new line characters for the blank cities. Can you just get the csv with blank string in those locations instead?

Comment: @Ben CSV files are coming from 3rd party, I can't modify it. It should be read row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String::Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_)
Provide both the comma and newline characters as delimiters and provide None in the option to retain empty values.

Answer (score -1):

I think this code will help you. You can customize it as per your needs:

```
private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile1(string csv_file_path1)
  {

   DataTable table2 = new DataTable("Real");

   try
   {
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader1 = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path1))
    {
     csvReader1.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
     csvReader1.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
     string[] colFields = csvReader1.ReadFields();

     foreach (string column in colFields)
     {
      DataColumn datecolumn2 = new DataColumn(column);
      datecolumn2.AllowDBNull = true;
      table2.Columns.Add(datecolumn2);
     }

     while (!csvReader1.EndOfData)
     {
      string[] fieldData1 = csvReader1.ReadFields();
      table2.Rows.Add(fieldData1);
     }
    }

    foreach (DataRow dr in table2.Rows)
    {
     foreach (DataColumn dc in table2.Columns)
     {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString()))
      {
       dr[dc.ColumnName] = DBNull.Value;
      }
     }
    }

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    MessageBox.Show("Select New File");
   }

   return table2;

  }
```

Comment: May I know the reason I mean where its getting failed?